# Android Error Importing Library which references R resource

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I have an Android Library that I've uploaded to Artifactory and include in a separate application using

```
compile 'com:mycompany:mylibrary:0.0.1'
```

The gradle syncs properly and imports the library to my 'External Libraries', however when I run the application I get errors referencing code in the library:

```
// Code in my android library dependency
AUTHORITY = getContext().getString(R.string.content_provider_authority);
                                   ^ error: package R does not exist
```

If anyone has ideas on what's going on please let me know.

Comment: To clarify, where is this line of code which causes the error? Is it code from the library? Or is this a line of code which you wrote yourself?

Comment: Both -- I created a library which I uploaded to a local artifact repository (Artifactory). The error was from a line in this library because the resources were missing in the jar file. I fixed it by publishing the artifact as a .arr file instead of .jar. The .arr file includes the resources, among other things.

Comment: I guess my real question was whether the line of code was from the library or from the application. I think you already answered that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed a **.aar** file not a **.jar** file for android library dependency. The [**.aar** file](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) is a zip file which contains everything you need for your android library.

Answer (score 0):

1. For AUTHORIY, you should use constant string like this:

private static final String AUTHORITY = "your_package"

2. For your case, make sure you check gen folder when exporting to jar files

Comment: I believe that in the context, naming the variable in all caps is reasonable. The OP is loading the string value from a resource, and so is unable to declare the variable as `final`. However, the value should never change after it is initialized, so the convention of all upper case communicates this to the programmer even though the compiler won't enforce it.